# How to show only certain value in Google Charts axes?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

So I have a chart which has many dates. Is it possible somehow to  show only certain titles. For example first, last and every 5 between them?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `ticks` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#configuration-options) to set custom axis labels

to use values from the data, use the [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getValue) method on the `DataTable`
`getValue` takes two arguments, `row` & `column`

the rows and columns are *zero-based*, the first of each is `0`
`data.getValue(0, 0)`

to get the last value in the first column, use `getNumberOfRows() - 1`
`data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0)`

to get every fifth element, use the modulus operator `%`,
keep in mind this will include the first element,
and possibly the last, depending on the number of rows...

```
// add every fifth
var tickMarks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    tickMarks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
  }
}
```

see following working snippet, which only adds the first and last...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Units');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2016,0,1), 100],
      [new Date(2016,0,3), 120],
      [new Date(2016,0,30), 110],
      [new Date(2016,1,1), 170],
      [new Date(2016,1,10), 180],
      [new Date(2016,1,25), 110],
      [new Date(2016,2,1), 170],
      [new Date(2016,2,14), 171],
      [new Date(2016,2,20), 172],
      [new Date(2016,3,12), 173],
      [new Date(2016,3,16), 174],
      [new Date(2016,3,19), 175],
      [new Date(2016,4,12), 176],
      [new Date(2016,4,16), 177],
      [new Date(2016,4,19), 178],
      [new Date(2016,5,12), 179],
      [new Date(2016,5,16), 180],
      [new Date(2016,5,19), 181],
      [new Date(2016,6,12), 190],
      [new Date(2016,6,16), 192],
      [new Date(2016,6,19), 196],
      [new Date(2016,6,24), 192],
      [new Date(2016,7,12), 190],
      [new Date(2016,7,16), 192],
      [new Date(2016,7,19), 196]
    ]);

    var tickMarks = [];

    //add first
    tickMarks.push(data.getValue(0, 0));

    //add last
    tickMarks.push(data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0));

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      hAxis: {
        format: 'M/d/yy',
        ticks: tickMarks
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: sure, you can provide any value you want. I changed the above answer to explain a little better...